# Hotdeck imputation (VIM): strange imputation value fix

Tags: r, missing-data, imputation

I have a panel dataset with some missing values, because there are missing values I am using the hotdeck imputation from the VIM package to impute these values. I have also looked at MICE (Amelia crashes unfortunately), but given that I have specifically selected variables that do not vary much over time I want to just pick the closest time observation for imputation.

However, my problem is that for some entries I am getting value 1.00 returned. Now I looked at my data and it seems that the value 1.00 is returned when there is absolutely no data available to impute upon (which is fine), however there are also a few 1.00 entries which seem off. Strangely they also seem to be almost all packed into the same year (1999), although there are some spread across the data as well.

Below is the code I ran and an example of data that I encounter. What I am looking to fix is to have these entries filled in with the hotdeck method as well (Last observation carried forward)

```
 df<- hotdeck(df, domain_var = "country", ord_var=c("year"))
```

In the example Var1 is correctly coded, Var2 and Var3 contain errors

```
Country    Year       Var1        Var2         Var3
Austria    1997        3.3        90.47        54.41
Austria    1998        3.3        90.77        53.23
Austria    1999        3.3         1.00        1.00000
Austria    2000        3.3        92.06        1.00000
Austria    2001        3.3        91.98        1.00000
```